# Why is a React-Native android app size so big?

Tags: android-studio, apk, react-native

My current Signed APK project `app-universal-release` is about 30MB and `app-armeabi-v7a-release` is about 9MB!

I have set the following:

```
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true
```

So I try test it with a new app (I signed it too).

With the hello word! app, I get 27MB and 8.5MB

It is too much. I saw in Play Store many 1MB and 2MB apps!

Do I have to use Android Studio to reduce the size of the APK file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
release {
    //Enable the proguard
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), "proguard-rules.pro"

    //Other parameters
    debuggable false
    jniDebuggable false
    renderscriptDebuggable false
    signingConfig playStoreConfig //Add your own signing config
    pseudoLocalesEnabled false
    zipAlignEnabled true
}
```